# Kindle paperwhite screensaver consuming power

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, e-ink

I have just purchased the latest gen kindle paper-white (2016 300ppi) and received a case with a magnetic cover. Doing a little testing with the magnet in the corner, I can see that even when I turn my kindle screen off using the button, the magnet being pulled away powers it on. When I place the magnet on the kindle again, the kindle displays the screen-saver rather than turning the screen off.

From what I understand about e-ink technology the technology is [bi-stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_Ink) meaning the actual display of the image doesn't drain power, its the refresh of the page (as well as wifi, the back-light, touch response and the cpu processes). On the lowest brightness setting the kindle has an almost unnoticeable light source which can be seen in the dark as a glow. When I use the magnet and the screen-saver comes on, the light *appears* to shut off completely.

That said, a number of sources on-line say this light stays on when the screen-saver is displayed which will still drain the battery over a long period of time. I don't think this to be true but I can't confirm it either. Is this true of the current gen model, older models or not?

Comment: When the cover is closed, the magnet should trigger the screensaver and the backlight should turn off completely. You can verify this by bringing your kindle into a very dark room, such as a closet or bathroom with the lights turned off. The screen light should not stay on at all when the cover is closed. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: The issue _appears_ to be fixed - if you close, then open, then close the cover the second closing appears to perform the same action as closing it when it isn't in "slide to unlock" mode. This was a recent update a few days ago.